# Add second non null condition to Django FilterSet

Tags: django

How do you add a non-null constraint to a second field on a drf_filters.FilterSet?

In the case below, I would like to impose a second constraint that the model field called "obsolete" is not None.

```
class MyFilterSet(drf_filters.FilterSet):
    
    uploaded = drf_filters.IsoDateTimeFilter(
        field_name='uploaded_at',
        lookup_expr='gt',
        required=True
    )
```

Comment: so `obsolete` is what kind of field?

Comment: DateTime (the date the object was marked as obsolete). So I want to check that obsolete is null

Answer (score 0):

You can work with a [**`BooleanFilter`** <sup>[readthedocs.io]</sup>](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#booleanfilter):

```
class MyFilterSet(drf_filters.FilterSet):
    uploaded = drf_filters.IsoDateTimeFilter(
        field_name='uploaded_at', lookup_expr='gt', required=True
    )
    is_obsolete = drf_filters.BooleanField(
        field_name='obsolete', lookup_expr='isnull', required=True
    )
```

This will thus add an extra boolean filter that if `True` will filter such that the `obsolete` field should be `NULL`/`None`, and if `False` *not* be `None`/`NULL`.

Comment: How would you force the is_obsolete filter to be True always as opposed to passing in True.

Comment: @Ajax: filter already in the `ModelViewSet`, so `queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(obsolete=None)`.